# Taking the mean of values in a dataset while ignoring two values

Tags: python, numpy, mean

I have a dataset `dod`, and I want to take the mean of values in `dod`. In `dod` there fill values, with values of `-9.99`, and values of `0`. I would like to ignore those values when taking the mean.

So far I can only ignore the fill values:

```
dod = f.variables['dod_modis_flg1'][i]

def nan_if(arr, value):
    return np.where(arr == value, np.nan, arr)
mean = np.nanmean([nan_if(dod, -9.99)])
print(mean)
```

Does anyone know how I can ignore the values of `0` as well, while taking the mean?

Comment: Why don't you nanize your zeros also just like you did for -9.99 and take `nanmean` ? `[nan_if(nan_if(dod,-9.99),0)]`

Comment: Please post a snapshot of your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either replace unwanted values with `nan`s, but that will change your original array:

```
dod[~numpy.logical_or(numpy.isclose(dod, 0), numpy.isclose(dod, -9.99))] = numpy.nan
numpy.mean(dod)
```

Three additional boolean arrays need to be allocated to perform the operation, but no additional float arrays are created.

Or only select the values you want and take the mean:

```
tmp = dod[~numpy.logical_or(numpy.isclose(dod, 0), numpy.isclose(dod, -9.99))]
numpy.mean(tmp)
```

but that will additionally create an intermediate float array

```
numpy.may_share_memory(tmp, dod)   # False
```

Third option is to create a masked array like:

```
tmp2 = numpy.ma.masked_where(
    numpy.logical_or(numpy.isclose(dod, 0), numpy.isclose(dod, -9.99)),
    dod,
    copy=False
)
numpy.mean(tmp2)
```

which only creates the additional boolean arrays but no intermediate float array:

```
numpy.may_share_memory(tmp2.data, dod)   # True
```

### Conclusion

- If you are allowed to modify the input array, do so (option 1)
- If you are not allowed to modify the input array, create a temporary masked array (option 3)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You can do it all in one line - I'm just creating the `new_array` variable for clarity:

```
# get the dod array but without -9.99 or 0.
new_array = dod[~np.isin(dod, [-9.99, 0])]
np.nanmean(new_array)
```

Note: requires numpy >= 1.13